# Initiating a Coroutine in a public static void in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, c#-4.0, coroutine, ienumerator

Yeah, I'm literally stuck on a simple Coroutine. In my Unity game I've been trying to figure out how to use something like this in a public static void:

```
StartCoroutine(ExampleCoroutine())
```

I understand that there is no way to use that line in a public static void, but I'm trying to find a workaround that would do the same thing. So far the internet hasn't been a help, but the closest I've gotten to my problem being solved was something about creating an instance. I didn't understand it because I am a mere novice, but it might be a lead as this is the error I get while creating:

```
error CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(IEnumerator)'
```

The IEnumerator that the Coroutine starts is marked public static, if that helps at all.
Thank you for your time and humouring my stupidity

EDIT: I was asked to show more code, so here I go!

```
public static void NeedsToBeAccessedElsewhere()
{
     StartCoroutine(NeedsDeley());
     //Do Stuff
}

public static IEnumerator NeedsDelay()
{
     //results
}
```

Comment: No. I'm trying to start a Coroutine in a public static void.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm wondering what to do.

Comment: I shared an error that said the same thing.

Comment: Done with the edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A coroutine always needs an instance of `MonoBehaviour` that is responsible for executing it. Therefore `StartCoroutine` is not a `static` but an instance method and has to be called on an instance of `MonoBehavior`.

Thus if your method is `static` you either have to pass in a `MonoBehaviour` reference like e.g.

```
public static void NeedsToBeAccessedElsewhere(MonoBehaviour instance)
{
     instance.StartCoroutine(NeedsDeley());
}

public static IEnumerator NeedsDelay()
{
     //results
}
```

Or as a fallback you could make sure there is a default behavior that is created on demand

```
public class CoroutineExecuter : MonoBehaviour { }
```

and do

```
private static CoroutineExecuter instance;

public static void NeedsToBeAccessedElsewhere()
{
    if(!instance)
    {
        instance = FindObjectOfType<CoroutineExecuter>();

        if(!instance)
        {
            instance = new GameObject ("CoroutineExecuter").AddComponent<CoroutineExecuter>();
        }
    }

    instance.StartCoroutine(NeedsDeley());
}

public static IEnumerator NeedsDelay()
{
     //results
}
```

---

Note, however, in general: You commented `// Do stuff` but have in mind that calling. `StartCoroutine` is terminated immediately and does not delay the method calling it. If this was your plan you should rather pass in a callback like

```
public static IEnumerator NeedsDelay(Action afterDelay)
{
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

     afterDelay?.Invoke();
}
```

and use it like e.g.

```
instance.StartCoroutine(NeedsDelay(() =>
{
    Debug.Log("Delay has finished");
}));
```

Comment: Sorry for getting back late: I got this error: Error CS7036: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter 'instance' of 'MyScript.MyVoid(MonoBehaviour)'

Comment: @Spectre well then you didn't pass in the required instance ;)